# What does extension-provided configuration mean in Config Snapshot?

Tags: 8, configuration

> Configuration Snapshot enables snapshotting of **extension-provided**
>   configuration. It's used by Configuration Synchronizer to support
>   updating configuration provided by modules, themes, and the install
>   profile.

Recently I checked my database and found there are two tables
config
and 
config_snapshot

I found that the module [Config Snapshot](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_snapshot) creates the table config_snapshot table

While reading through project page text,I see it says "it enables snapshotting of **extension-provided** configuration"
What does extension-provided configuration mean ?

Comment: “Extension” seems just to be being used as a catch-all term for modules, themes and installation profiles. Those three are the only things that can provide config outside of core, so it seems a safe bet

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Clive,

> “Extension” seems just to be being used as a catch-all term for
>   modules, themes and installation profiles. Those three are the only
>   things that can provide config outside of core, so it seems a safe bet